# Is there a way to do "for loop expansion" in bash or zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, zsh

Is there a shell (bash,zsh,??) that supports something like this?

```
git branch -D <feature1,feature2,feature3>
```

that would effectively make a transformation to:

```
for BRANCH in feature1 feature2 feature3; do git branch -D $BRANCH; done
```

Comment: I would doubt it. That's wildly unsafe. That comma delimited string could be a perfectly valid argument to that command. The shell can't know.

Comment: That reasoning is a bit weak. You can do `mkdir f{1,2,3}` and it will get expanded to `mkdir f1 f2 f3`. If you cared about commas you can just do `mkdir 'f{1,2,3}'` to escape expansion. I don't see why a shell couldn't expand something like `^1,2,3^` or w/e to a for loop.

Comment: `printf '%s\0' feature1 feature2 feature3 | xargs -0 -n1 <command>`?

Comment: I know about xargs, this is specifically about sugar to make this common case easier. I guess you could write a helper bash function..

Comment: @WilliamCasarin That's not what you are asking for though. You could do *exactly* that with your `git branch` command too but it doesn't do what you want here. The difference is how it interacts with the rest of the command. Though I'll grant it is only a mostly compelling reason.

Comment: Yes, sugar for that absolutely could exist it would just be decidedly less generally useful and a function to do this is simple enough to write ad-hoc. `gbD() { for arg; do git branch -D "$arg"; done; } gbD branch1 branch2 branch3`.

Comment: that's hard-coded to git branch, I don't care about git branch. it was just an example :|

Answer (score 3):

No, because this is not nearly as useful as it sounds. Most commands accept multiple arguments already, including `git branch -D`:

```
$ git branch -D foo bar baz
Deleted branch foo (was 9e9d099).
Deleted branch bar (was 9e9d099).
Deleted branch baz (was 9e9d099).
```

Commands that don't accept this typically have a good reason not to. For example, `convert "$file" output.jpg` has an explicit output path, and naively looping over filenames would just overwrite the output.

For these things, `zsh` has short form `for` loops if it helps:

```
for f (foo bar baz) convert "$f.png" "$f.jpg"
```

Comment: :( It's useful for cases that don't support multiple arguments like that

Comment: It's a shame there is no expansion syntax, but that short form is pretty nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
##
# Run the given command (first args up to `--`)
# on each of the following args, one at a time.
# The name `map` is tongue-in-cheek.
#
# Usage: map [cmd] -- [args]
map() {
    local -a cmd
    local arg
    while [[ $1 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            --) break;;
        esac
        cmd+=( "$1" )
        shift
    done
    shift
    for arg; do
        "${cmd[@]}" "$arg"
    done
}
```

Comment: Haha I had something similar half written but this looks a bit better. Thanks!

Comment: You're kind of reinventing `xargs`: `printf "%s\n" "$@" | xargs -L 1 "${cmd[@]}"`

Comment: @glennjackman That command looks [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012780/is-there-a-way-to-do-for-loop-expansion-in-bash-or-zsh#comment-50052936).